# How two compare two rows from two different dataframes pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need some help in comparing two rows from two dataframes. First, I need to find the common value, that in this case is a value from a column called MX (it will never change) and once they have matched I need to compare the whole row to  verify if the values are the same and if they indeed are the same is just fine (print ok) but if they are not or even one value are not I need to see which value it should be or where is the mismatch.

#This is the data that is fixed and do not suffer modiffications (to compare with).

```
Data:
dataframe1:
        MX       DT          MN        SC        CS       LN
0       1        11          1        400       1025    802436
1       5        21          4        240       3201    4025731
2      11        25          19       1428      2000    2013654
3      15        36          17       1005      6028    4251367
4      23        55          21        222      4017    1468532
5      38        32          33       426       4892    8347561

dataframe2:
       MX          DT          MN        SC        CS      LN
0      11          25          19       1428      2000   2013654
```

This is a case in which they both match in row MX:11. The whole row is the same in both cases but it will be cases in which they will not such as compared with:

```
dataframe3:
       MX          DT          MN        SC        CS      LN
0      11          22          0       1427      2000   2013654
```

In summary, I need to know where is the mismatch and which should be the expected value (dataframe1) if the value from any row is different from dataframe1.
It is better trying in pandas or passing it to dictionaries as key:values and cheking it?

Comment: Do you mean `df1[df1["MX"].isin(df2["MX"])].eq(df2.to_numpy())`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HenryYik . Yes, I obtain `False` and `True`, but how can I print out the correct value when is `False`?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way (I tweaked the data a little so the difference can be shown):

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'MX': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 11, 3: 15, 4: 23, 5: 38},
                    'DT': {0: 11, 1: 21, 2: 25, 3: 36, 4: 55, 5: 32},
                    'MN': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 19, 3: 17, 4: 21, 5: 33},
                    'SC': {0: 400, 1: 240, 2: 1428, 3: 1005, 4: 222, 5: 426},
                    'CS': {0: 1025, 1: 3201, 2: 2000, 3: 6028, 4: 4017, 5: 4892},
                    'LN': {0: 802436, 1: 4025731, 2: 2013654, 3: 4251367, 4: 1468532, 5: 8347561}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'MX': {0: 11}, 'DT': {0: 26}, 'MN': {0: 19},
                    'SC': {0: 1428}, 'CS': {0: 2001}, 'LN': {0: 2013654}})
```

Filter df1 with `isin` and then slice `df1` base on row of boolean values:

```
df1 = df1.loc[df1["MX"].isin(df2["MX"])]

print (df1.loc[:, (~df1.eq(df2.to_numpy()).iloc[0]).tolist()])

   DT    CS
2  25  2000
```

Comment: Thank you @HenryYik . Also, how could I remove the index, in this answer is 2, just to see the values?

Comment: Don't see the actual need to remove it, but you can obtain the result as a series by adding `.iloc[0]` at the end.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. It´s correct as you print it, but I refer that I just need to remove the 2 from the output. I mean, just the columns with their respective values and names.