# Replace rows in a dataframe with rows from another dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pulled subsections of a large data frame into smaller df chunks where I use masking to find certain issues through the text column. I have then assigned a value to the issue column e.g booking error is now 1 not 0.

I want to now merge this smaller dataframe back into the large original dataframe, replacing the rows that existed there before. The idea being everything in the original dataframe is identical except all it has gained is the new errors of 1 that I have added.

df

```
chatid text                  card_declined booking_error website_error
401    hi my card declined..        0              0             0
402    you website crashed..        0              0             0
403    hi my card declined..        0              0             0
```

df1

```
chatid text                  card_declined booking_error website_error
    1    hi my card declined..        1              0             0
    2    you website crashed..        1              0             0
    3    hi my card declined..        1              0             0
```

Its important to note that although the rows exist in both dataframes the indexes are different.

This was the conditional mask I made which was assigned df1:

```
dec = ['declined','card issue']
df1 = df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(dec),na=False)]
df1['promo code'] = 1
```

I tried this but got the following error:

```
for i in df:
    if df['chatid'] == df1['chatid']:
        df['card_declined'] = 1
```

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

I have tried using pd.merge but that didn't seem to make any amendments to the original df. I also tried concat but obv got duplicate rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: chatid it is a unique identifier

Comment: Try looking at the answer to [How to compare two different rows in to different dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359060/how-two-compare-two-rows-from-two-different-dataframes-pandas) to fix your comparation.